# Magento Developer Certification for Magento 1 or 2

Tags: magento2, magento-1, certification

I am a Magento 1.x developer and preparing for Magento certification. I may appear in exam for certification in next 5 to 6 months. If Magento 2.x is released before my exam then will i have to prepare for Magento 2.x also?

Comment: Nope, i don't thinks so.... Would be very strange... Didn't you get a email from them ? Just mail back and ask, there very nice people and are glad to help you. At least that was my experiance with them. Or email me private and i will give you a address to mail to.. Good luck with your exam. I also still have to do my exam...

Answer (score 16):

No. The Magento 2 certification will be a separate exam. You will not see Magento 2 content on the existing certification exams.

For awhile, being officially Magento 2 trained will substitute for Magento 2 certification until Magento 2 certification is available.

Comment: Welcome to MageSE ;) 
Is the training the Magento Fundamentals course?

Comment: Haha, thanks. I always lurk, but I've been here since Ben first proposed it. :) Yes, the Magento 2 Fundamentals course.

Comment: That means if I passed certification for magento 1.9.x now then i will have to prepare again for magento 2 exam. How will be importance of magento 1.9.x certifaction?

Comment: The M1 certification will still be of value for quite awhile, Jai. M2 will need to be in place for a significant period of time before M2 certification will begin.

Comment: @sherrie. So should i wait for M2 certification? because i might take exam of in 6 months so if M2 is release by that time then i should take M2 certification. What you suggest?

Comment: @Jai: It's recommended to take M1 certification now as it will still be valuable for quite some time. You're probably looking at more than 6 months for M2 certification, tho I don't have an exact date.

Comment: Actually i dont want to appear in exam again and again. if M1 would become useless after few months then i would consider M2. thats reason for my confusion,

Comment: @Jai: M1 certification will be still be valid for M1 projects which will continue on for quite some time. We're supporting M1 on our end for three years post M2 GA.

Answer (score 0):

I am a Magento developer from Magestore.

About your questions, Magento 2.x certification is now still not available. Maybe the template will be different from Magento 1.x certification.

Don't worry. Let's practice and try hard for your exam.

If you are not much confident with your knowledge, you can go to our FREE Magento Test Tool at the link: http://bit.ly/1OUri5R

It's totally FREE and we make it to help developers to improve Magento skills.

Hope it help!

Comment: When are you planning to add Magento2 .x questions in your test series?

Comment: Hi @amitshree, we are on the way to develop Magento 2 Test.
We want to prepare best questions for you guys.

If you guys want to contribute questions to us, let's fill it out here: 
http://bit.ly/1ZEYeTT
We will have some "secret reward" for you :)

In the next 2 weeks, it will be officially completed.
Hope that you guys can wait :)

Comment: Sounds Awesome :) I think there is some issue with the link you have shared.

Comment: @amitshree, which link bro? :)
Can you make it clear?

Comment: bit.ly/1ZEYeTT where people can contribute questions to Magento2 :)

Comment: Here it is, bro :)
http://bit.ly/1ZEYeTT

Comment: @TracyPhung   .thx and I am also refering Magestore ebooks for my certification they are really helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Jai. We are on the way to make Magento 2 Ebooks. 
We will release soon :)

Comment: Thats great @TracyPhung. waiting for that. (y)