# Certification and training - Magento 1 vs Magento 2

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, certification

Looking to get certified as a Magento developer however finding the [certification page](https://magento.com/training/catalog/certification) a bit confusing. It looks as though all of the certs are for Magento 1 and but you can do Magento U Courses for Magento 2.

Questions:

1. Are there certifications yet for Magento 2
2. Would it be best to only get certifications in Magento 2 if they exist
3. If Magento 2 certifications dont exist is it still worth getting Magento 1 certified

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No, there are no certifications for Magento 2 yet (as of writing). Magento has expressed in various webinars and elsewhere that they won't be creating the certification for M2 until there's a solid base of real-world experience working with it (on the part of merchants and developers).

I expect we will start hearing about it around Imagine 2017 (April). This is purely speculation.

Until then, there is a 'Magento 2 Trained' program, but to my knowledge it is only available to Magento solution partners. https://magento.com/training/catalog/magento-2-trained-partner-program-mp

2. Not entirely applicable, but this is a matter of preference. Do you work with M1? Then it may be of value.
3. If you already work with Magento 1 extensively, there is no harm in pursuing certification for it before the M2 certification comes out. A lot of knowledge about how Magento works will translate, so anything you learn in the process will be of value. If you don't have Magento 1 experience and will only be working with Magento 2 going forward, you're probably better off waiting.

This is a pretty common question, so also see the various related questions/answers on the sidebar, including:

- [Magento Developer Certification for Magento 1 or 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83331/magento-developer-certification-for-magento-1-or-2?rq=1)
- [Certification - how will magento 2 release affect it?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8959/certification-how-will-magento-2-release-affect-it?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

My response is based on my personal experience from attending the [Magento 2 Developer Bootcamp](https://magento.com/training/catalog/fundamentals-of-magento-2-development-instructor-led-ondemand) offered by Magento.

1. **Yes**, but *not* in the sense you're referring to. [The Recognized Magento 2 Fundamentals Developer Assessment](https://magento.com/training/catalog/catalog/product/view/id/31670/s/knowledge-assessment-magento2-fundamentals/12962/). The [Fundamentals of Magento 2 Development](https://magento.com/training/catalog/fundamentals-of-magento-2-development) on-demand course and it's accompanying [classroom add-on](https://magento.com/training/catalog/fundamentals-of-magento-2-development-instructor-led) are **prerequisites** for the assessment. We were told that we *would* receive a certificate upon successful completion of the assessment, albeit not the official Magento 2 Developer certification.
   The following description is from Magento's website.

   > For employers, it provides recognition of the active learning and
   > knowledge transfer experienced by the participant in completing the
   > Magento 2 Fundamentals curriculum.

   Some folks speculated that the assessment is being offered as an an interim solution for the high demand for Magento 2 certifications until the official certification is available (rumored to be Imagine 2017).
2. That depends on what you need the certification for to begin with. Work? Pleasure? Either way, I don't see how having both would ever hurt you.
3. See the answer to question two.