# Magento1 certification scope?

Tags: magento2

I am planned to write magento1 certification . If they start magento2 certification then magento1 certification is not valid ?

Answer (score 0):

Magento 1 certification will always be valid. It just only applies to Magento 1.

Once Magento 2 certification comes out, you would need to test again for that (if you chose to do so). They're separate things.

See also: [Certification and training - Magento 1 vs Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126194/certification-and-training-magento-1-vs-magento-2)

Answer (score 0):

> The importance of Magento 1 Certification will remain same.

There are a lot of changes between Magento 1 vs Magento 2. There are no magento 2 certifications available yet (Posted date).

If you are planing to write certification, i am always recommended to take the exam.

For some answers you can read [Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126194/certification-and-training-magento-1-vs-magento-2/126492) [Link 2](https://community.magento.com/t5/Off-Topic/Magento-2-certification-exams/td-p/176)