# Magento 2, certification exam

Tags: magento2, certification

Can any one please share links for the

> study material for magento 2 certification exam (dump)

I know many questions related to this is asked before many times. But all those question are not satisfactory, and as we know day by day era is changing, with positive vibes, I want to know is something get update regarding magento2. Hope some body can help me for the same.

**I HAVE REFERED THESE LINKS AS WELL**

For Developer Certification: [Fundamentals of Magento 2 Development](https://u.magento.com/fundamentals-of-magento-2-development#.WMfst-2RJ74)

For Frontend Certification: [Core Principles of Theming in Magento 2](https://u.magento.com/core-principles-theming-magento2#.WMfwmu2RJ74)

except these if any information is updated regarding this. I am glad to thank for the participation of that guy who help me for the same.

**Thank you.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 2018-04-30:**

Magento U has now released three Magento 2 certifications. There's also a [Frontend Developer Certification under work](https://twitter.com/benmarks/status/990992486863654920) that should be available within several months, and I've heard rumor of a JS Certification a year or two down the road. You can view all certifications on the [Magento U website](https://u.magento.com/certification).

Study guides for each certification can be requested here: [Download A Free Magento Study Guide](https://u.magento.com/free-study-guide)

The available M2 certifications are:

[**Magento 2 Certified Solution Specialist**](https://u.magento.com/certified-magento2-solution-specialist): *"Magento 2 Certified Solution Specialists have demonstrated a thorough understanding of how to leverage Magento 2 functionality to satisfy ecommerce business goals according to best practices."*

[**Magento 2 Certified Professional Developer**](https://u.magento.com/magento-2-certified-professional-developer): *"Magento 2 Certified Professional Developers have demonstrated a deep understanding of how to customize Magento 2 source code in accordance with Magento best practices."* This is targeted at backend developers with 1.5+ years experience with Magento 2.

[**Magento 2 Certified Associate Developer**](https://u.magento.com/magento-2-certified-associate-developer-exam): *"This exam is for a developer who is beginning their career as a Magento Developer and is designed to validate the student's skills and knowledge of Magento 2 in the areas of: UI modifications, database changes, admin modifications, customizations, catalog and checkout structure, and functionality changes."*

Upcoming: Magento 2 Certified Frontend Developer

---

**Original Answer:**

There is no Magento 2 certification exam yet, so there are no resources for studying/training for the M2 certification exam. Anything saying otherwise, as of this writing, is lying.

The latest rumors I've heard are that M2 certification will be coming sometime after the release of Magento 2.2. It's likely M2 certification will be released in late 2017 or early 2018.

See also: [Certification and training - Magento 1 vs Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126194/certification-and-training-magento-1-vs-magento-2)

Comment: @Ryan m2 exam is live so you can update your answer

Answer (score 3):

You can get sample study guide from below link, Which is written by Joseph Maxwell and he is one of the first to have taken and passed the Certified Developer exam

It has 177 pages full of helpful and informative content. This not only makes you a better developer, but will help you pass the test.

https://swiftotter.com/technical/certifications/magento-2-certified-developer-study-guide

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 certifications:

- MAGENTO 2 CERTIFIED SOLUTION SPECIALIST https://u.magento.com/certified-magento2-solution-specialist#.WtnrBnVuZhE
- MAGENTO 2 CERTIFIED PROFESSIONAL DEVELOPER https://u.magento.com/magento-2-certified-professional-developer#.WtnrCHVuZhE
- MAGENTO 2 CERTIFIED ASSOCIATE DEVELOPER EXAM https://u.magento.com/magento-2-certified-associate-developer-exam#.WtnrC3VuZhE

Answer (score 1):

You can try Magento questions dump with [this link](https://blog.willfeeling.com/category/magento2-quizz/). I had follow and pass exam with that questions dump 70% correct.

Comment: is it useful for magento2 professional certificate?

Comment: yes, of course!

Comment: This is useful for the new Adobe certification ad0-e703?

Answer (score 1):

I practiced here https://m2professional.dev, but real expirince was  more reliable on the final exam.

Answer (score 1):

**Latest study guide certifications:updated [21 August 2020]**:

- **[AD0-E700]:** *Adobe Certified Expert Magento Commerce Business Practitioner*  [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/87jLctNB6KxM0/)
- **[AD0-E701]:** *Adobe Certified Expert-Magento Commerce Front-End Developer* [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/lJWBfPhvp5npA/)
- **[AD0-E702]:** *Adobe Certified Professional—Magento Commerce Developer*  [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/saM506xrYKi0p/)
- **[AD0-E703]:** *Adobe Certified Expert - Magento Commerce Developer* [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/OwpmK2JcACwhl/)
- **[AD0-E704]:** *Adobe Certified Master Magento Commerce Architect* [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/PTidDHsT5JgyB/)
- **[AD0-E705]:** *Adobe Certified Expert-Magento Commerce JavaScript Developer*  [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/ZDus3If2u1rQf/)
- **[AD0-E706]:** *Adobe Certified Expert-Magento Commerce Cloud Developer* [available since June 2018] [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/GrkbPktpWMkkb/)
- **[Adobe AD0-E707]** Adobe Certified Expert Magento Commerce Order Management Developer [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/K2Wjl6Na3BY0h/)